# Which type of current generates more heat in a nicrome wire?

Tags: ac, dc, heat

Is it AC, DC or half wave?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why do you expect them to be different?

Comment: @Hearth, Isn’t there any difference sir?

Comment: I'm not a sir. And no, there is no significant difference unless you start talking about skin effect and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming AC is measured in RMS and does not have a particularly high frequency (MHz or higher), as is the half-wave, then they would all produce the exact same amount of heat.

Heat would be dictated by the power dissipated by the wire.
Therefore.

$$ P = V \cdot I $$

The current is likewise determined by the resistance of the wire

$$ I = \frac{V}{R} $$

So power, which is all lost as heat here is...

$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} $$

R and V wont change between AC or DC presuming V is represented as RMS and not peak to peak. Therefore power will be the same and governed by the above equation regardless. Keep in mind this means the peak of V would be higher than the DC value as AC and even higher still as half-wave, and it only works with RMS values.

The reason the frequency above matters is that if you are talking high frequencies into the MHz range and beyond then you get skinning effects that might effect the apparent resistance of the wire, in which case the R value above would need to be adjusted to see what sort of heat output you'd get in that case. But if you're dealing with reasonably lower frequencies this effect should be negligible.